# Wordpress Post Category Names Link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

After going several google searches i've accomplish this code (Not too good on PHP)

```
     <div>

    <?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );

    $catlinks = get_category_link( $categories);


    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {

        echo '<a href=" '.$catlink->link . '"> <h2>' . $category->name .'</h2></a>';


        $args['category'] = $category->term_id;
   } ?>

</div>
```

This code displays a loop of Wordpress Post Categories, im trying to get each category link, but i'm still not getting the right link.

Any help in advance would be great.

Thanks Rodrigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it pretty close.

You'll want to run [`get_category_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) against the ID of the `$category` in your `foreach` loop.

That looks like this:

```php
<?php
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"> <h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></a>';
}
?>
```

So, all together, your whole code should read:

```php
<div>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '"> <h2>' . $category->name . '</h2></a>';
   }
   ?>
</div>
```

Comment: TYVM Worked Perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_permalink` function. See the reference on [Wordpress site](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/)